# Bash time in seconds to human readable string

Tags: bash

I have the below code that i am trying to get to generate a human readable string of how long a script has run for, I have set `SECONDS` to 10,000 purely for testing.

The issue is currently it doesnt seem to be allowing me to add each `printf` statement to the `$TIMETOTAL` variable

```
    #!/bin/bash
    SECONDS=10000

    #CODE THAT WILL RUN GOES HERE

    T=$SECONDS
    D=$((T/60/60/24))
    H=$((T/60/60%24))
    M=$((T/60%60))
    S=$((T%60))

    TIMETOTAL=''

    if [ $D -gt 0 ]
    then
        $TIMETOTAL+=$(printf '%d days ' $D)
    fi
    if [ $H -gt 0 ]
    then
        $TIMETOTAL+=$(printf '%d hours ' $H)
    fi
    if [ $M -gt 0 ]
    then
        $TIMETOTAL+=$(printf '%d minutes ' $M)
    fi
    if [ $D -gt 0 ] || [ $H -gt 0 ] || [ $M -gt 0 ]
    then
        $TIMETOTAL+=$(printf 'and ')
    fi
    $TIMETOTAL+=$(printf '%d seconds\n' $S)
    echo $TIMETOTAL
```

Currently gives:

```
./map.sh: line 26: +=2: command not found
./map.sh: line 30: +=46: command not found
./map.sh: line 34: +=and: command not found
./map.sh: line 36: +=40: command not found
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `TIMETOTAL+=`, not `$TIMETOTAL+=` -- remove the leading `$`

Comment: That said, I'm a little unclear on why you're using subprocesses to run `printf` in. `timetotal+="$d days"` would be a lot more efficient. (Lowercase variables in accordance with POSIX guidelines specifying all-caps names for use by the shell and other POSIX-specified tools, whereas lowercase names are [reserved for application use](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) and guaranteed not to have undesired side effects on POSIX-specified tools).

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy this was mainly a hack together of something else and i completely forgot that doing it with a variable i wouldnt need printf at all... thanks i will clean it up

Comment: ...btw, to give you an example of all-caps names being meaningful to tools -- `$SECONDS`, by default in bash, evaluates to the number of seconds since the shell started up. If you were using `seconds` instead, you wouldn't be implicitly disabling that capability by writing to a variable under the same name as that builtin.